# Embed image in html custom template

Tags: apex, email-template, class, html

I have below HTML custom email template where the image insertion is failing. Can someone please help me?

**Code**

```
<html><table height="400" width="550" cellpadding="5" border="2" cellspacing="5">
<div style="width:550px;height:20px;font-size: 20px;border:1px solid #000;text-align: center;background:#F2D9B1;">Order Rejection Notification</div>
<tr height="400" valign="top">
<td style="color:#000000;font-size:12pt; background-color:#FEFCC9; font-family:arial;">
<p class=3DMsoNormal></p>

<p class=3DMsoNormal style=3D'margin-bottom:12.0pt'>This message serves as
confirmation that a recent order from within your territory was unable to
process due to the following reason(s):</p>

<ul type=3Ddisc>
 <li class=3DMsoNormal style=3D'mso-margin-top-alt:auto;mso-margin-bottom-a=
lt:auto;
     mso-list:l0 level1 lfo1;tab-stops:list .5in'><span style=3D'mso-fareas=
t-font-family:
     "Times New Roman"'>{RejectReason}</span></li>
</ul>

<p class=3DMsoNormal style=3D'margin-bottom:12.0pt'><br>
Sample Request Form Order <b>{OrderNo}</b> was rejected in <b>{Territory}</b> for <b>{Owner}</b>.<br>

<br>
<strong>Order Details:</strong><br>
<br>

Source Profile ID: {HCPProfileId}<br>
{HCPName}<br>
{ShipAddress1} <br>
{CityStateZip}</p>
<table class="MsoNormalTable" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody><tr><td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in"><p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b>NDC </b></p></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in"><p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b>Product Description</b></p></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in"><p class="MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center"><b>Ordered Quantity</b></p></td>
</tr>
<tr><td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in"><p class="MsoNormal">{NDC}</p></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in"><p class="MsoNormal">{ProductName}</p></td>
<td style="padding:0in 0in 0in 0in"><p class="MsoNormal">{Qty}</p></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<p class="MsoNormal"><br>

<br>
Thank you,<br>
iREP Team<br>
<br>
Please do not reply to this e-mail. This e-mail is for your information only.</p>

<p><img src="{!$Resource.Humira}" width="200" height="30" style=”display:block;” border=”0″/></p>
</td></tr>
</table></html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume that this is the image you're referring to:

```
img src="{!$Resource.Humira}
```

I'm guessing that Humira is actually a `zip` file and not the name of the image. Your code should include the path to the file from within your static resource. The zip file must also be set to "Public" so others outside your org can view it. Your code should look something like below:

```
<apex:image id="theImage" value="https://c.instance>.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?
  id=<document_id>&oid=<organization_id>" width="200" height="200"/>
```

For more, see this [KB Article](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Why-images-stored-as-static-resources-cannot-be-seen-in-emails-sent-using-VF-email-templates-1327108316482&language=en_US).

Comment: I don't have an apex page here. I need it only in html. :)

Comment: Let me first say that `apex:image` is the equivalent of html's `<img>` tag where `value` and `src` would also be equivalent. Is this a visualforce email template or a template for use with outbound email via services other than Apex? If the latter, see this [KB article](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005925).